# gradle, activiti , classes not found in tests

Tags: java, spring, gradle, activiti

kind of tricky question this time (for me)

I have the following setup:

```
src
---main
    ---java
        ---com.company.myclass.java
---test
    ---java
       ---com.test.company.myClassTest.java
       ---com.test.company.Testtest.java
    ---resources
       -testconfig.xml
build
---classes
    --- 'compiled classfiles in correct structure'
```

so pretty basic so far.

the thing is:

in testconfig.xml i have some tags like:

```
<element class="com.company.myclass" />
```

and the framework that needs this (activiti) cannot find the classes (ClassNotFoundException). (it is internaly using Spring for DI, if it helps to know)

I can however instantiate myclass in TestTest using new myclass().

The Framework however CAN find the classes alright, if i copy the files in question from src/main/java to src/test/java.

As the framework looks for its config on the classpath, and it finds the testconfig.xml, src/test/resources obviously IS on the classpath when testing, explaining why it works with classes copied to src/test/java.

But new myclass() != null and common sense suggest that src/main/java is too, what would i test if it wasn't?

I tried adding src/main to the classpath with

```
sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath += files(sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs)
```

but it did not do any good. What am i missing here?

UPDATE:

I should add that the activitiengine is instantiated in the test classes and the classes it needs need to be on 'the same classpath' as the engine was created. i don't know if this helps

Thanks and regards,

Attached my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'
def activitiversion = '5.14'
def bpmndir = 'src/main/resources/bpmn/'


sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            exclude '**/*.bpmn'
        }
    }
}

sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath += files(sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs) 

task renameBPMN(type: Copy) {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    from(bpmndir)
    into(bpmndir)
    include ('**/*.bpmn')
    rename ('(^.*)\\.(bpmn)$', '$1.bpmn20.xml')
}

compileJava.dependsOn renameBPMN

repositories {
   maven {
        url "http://10.95.17.191:9080/nexus/content/repositories/central"
    }
     maven {
        url "http://10.95.17.191:9080/nexus/content/repositories/repo.maven.apache.org/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.activiti', name: 'activiti-engine', version: activitiversion
    testCompile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.3.168'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.2'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-jdk14', version: '1.7.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain, why exactly your framework needs to inject `myclass` into the test. If this class is the one to be tested, I am wondering why it has to be injected, since it should know the class which the unit test is testing. If this class is just needed to test another class, you should consider to use a dummy class (which you place in the test folder), since you don't want to test more then one class at one time.

Comment: The Framework is a Buisnessprocessengine (activiti) and i want to test if the classes are correctly injected, if processvariables for new process instances are set etc.

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion would be to add the classpath of java/main to your test classpath. so change this

```
sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath += files(sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs)
```

to this:

```
sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath += files(sourceSets.main.output)
```

But still in my opinion you should not need to do this, because the binaries should already be an the classpath of test.

Comment: No such property: runtimeClasspath for class: org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet in java.runtimeClasspath.

I know, thats why i am pretty desperate for an answer here

Comment: Sorry I got confused by the sourceSets. You have to use the output of main, of course. There are the binaries of your sources.